# Upscaling with Realesrgan

Tags: c++, opencv, path, working-directory

I am trying to create a cpp file to use the `RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime` model to upscale an image.

I did the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <net.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

void upscaleWithRealESRGAN(const std::string& inputImagePath, const std::string& outputImagePath, int width, int height) {
    // Initialize ncnn net
    ncnn::Net realesrgan;

    // Load the pre-trained RealESRGAN model files
    realesrgan.load_param("assets/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime.param");
    realesrgan.load_model("assets/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime.bin");

    // Load the input image using OpenCV
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(inputImagePath, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (img.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error loading image from path: " << inputImagePath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Convert cv::Mat to ncnn::Mat
    ncnn::Mat in = ncnn::Mat::from_pixels(img.data, ncnn::Mat::PIXEL_BGR2RGB, img.cols, img.rows);

    if (width != 0 && height != 0) {
        ncnn::resize_bilinear(in, in, width, height);
    }

    // Create an extractor for inference
    ncnn::Extractor ex = realesrgan.create_extractor();

    // Input the image to the network
    ex.input("data", in);

    // Create an ncnn::Mat object for the output
    ncnn::Mat out;

    // Run the forward pass to get the upscaled image
    ex.extract("output", out);

    if (out.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Neural network output is empty." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Convert the output ncnn::Mat back to cv::Mat for saving
    cv::Mat out_cv(img.rows * 4, img.cols * 4, CV_8UC3); // Assuming x4 upscaling
    out.to_pixels(out_cv.data, ncnn::Mat::PIXEL_RGB2BGR);
    
    if (out_cv.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Conversion to cv::Mat resulted in an empty matrix." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Save the upscaled image using OpenCV
    cv::imwrite(outputImagePath, out_cv);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string inputPath = "input.jpg";  // Default input path
    std::string outputPath = "./output.png";  // Default output path
    int width = 0;  // Initialize with default 0
    int height = 0;  // Initialize with default 0

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-input" && i + 1 < argc) {
            inputPath = argv[i + 1];
            i++;  // skip next arg
        } else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-output" && i + 1 < argc) {
            outputPath = argv[i + 1];
            i++;  // skip next arg
        } else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-w" && i + 1 < argc) {
            width = std::stoi(argv[i + 1]);
            i++;  // skip next arg
        } else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-h" && i + 1 < argc) {
            height = std::stoi(argv[i + 1]);
            i++;  // skip next arg
        }
    }

    upscaleWithRealESRGAN(inputPath, outputPath, width, height);
    std::cout << "Upscaling completed!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
marcus@adming-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Code/_stable-diffusion-cpp/linux$ ./build/upscaler-ncnn -input result_15_42_256x256.png -w 512 -h 512
Error loading image!
Upscaling completed!
```

The image is in the folder as the `upscaler-ncnn`, however it does not execute.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your current working directory is set to the parent of `build`, the app is looking for the image file there, you need to either

1. move the image to the current working directory (the parent of `build`)
2. provide image path relative to current working directory `./build/result_15_42_256x256.png`
3. `cd` to the build directory, `cd build`